# Divide a JPA entity into two?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, relationship

Assume I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "customers)
public class CustomerImpl implements Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
private String surname;

@Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
private String country;

@Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
private String city;

@Column(name = "street", nullable = false)
private String street;

@Column(name = "zipCode", nullable = false)
private String zipCode;

// constructor + getters

}
```

I want to create a new class called **Address** which will hold country, street, city and zip code variables. The outlined variables will be then replaced with Address object to make code more readable and cleaner.

In my case, should the Address class be embedded or should I assign it as new entity and give @OneToOne relationship between Address and Customer?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on how you will store the data in your database. Do you have an `ADDRESSES` table or each table has `COUNTRY`, `CITY`, `STREET` and `ZIPCODE` as columns?

Comment: I don't have an 'addresses' table but I thought JPA generates the tables, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on your design. You can let JPA generate the tables for you (which I think is a good approach for integration testing purposes only) or work on an existent database model (which I think is a more robust approach and doesn't let you to shot in your own feet).

Comment: But if for example, I have another entity called "employee" which also requires an Address object. Will I have to create another address object like 'empAddress'? Or is there a way to use only one objects for more entities

Comment: I don't follow you. If you declare an `Address` class, then when you create a reference of `Employee`, let's say `employee`, then you will have to set the address by calling `employee.setAddress()`, despite which path you follow. The reference value used as parameter in `employee.setAddress` can be a reference already created or a new one, but that's basic Java programming.

Comment: I mean that for the 'Address' class, we have a 'customer' field on which the OneToOne annotation is written. But for example, I have another object Employee and I want to assign an address field for it as well. In the address class will we have two OneToOne relationships?

Comment: Probably you would need to create a `Person` class and `Customer` and `Employee` will extend from it. The `Address` would be bound to `Person`. But again, this is in case you have an `ADDRESS` table. If you don't, then just embed `Address` class in the necessary classes.

Comment: Thank you Luigi, how can I accept your answer mate?

Comment: I haven't posted an answer, just a comment. I could provide an answer later and then you may accept it if it solves your problems.

Comment: Please do that Luiggi :)

Answer (score 1):

To make your code more readable and cleaner you should create an ADRESSE table that contains country, city ..., and then you can use the @OneToOne relationship like this :

In the Customer class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Address address;
// Getter + Setter
```

In the Adresse class:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Customer customer;
```

Comment: This will work if OP has an `ADDRESS` table. If that's not the case, it would be better to use `@Embeddable`.

Comment: Isn't the JPA engine generating the tables?

Comment: No, but you can do it automatically only for testing purposes